# Queue values are not being accessed

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, system-verilog

I am planning to implement a maze routing program using Lee's algorithm. After searching some online resources, it seems that it requires a queue implementation for the BFS to work.  After storing the queue values in the register:

```verilog
   reg[9:0] queue[0:19];
   ...............
   temp<=queue[0];
   if(temp!= 0)begin
        j<=0;
         row<=temp[9:7];
         col<=temp[6:5];
         costp<=temp[4:0];
```

The control should go inside the `if` condition as the queue doesn't contain any zeros. But instead the control goes to the following prescript every time:

```verilog
    else begin
      temp<= 10'b 1110011001;
      error<=1;
      end
```

Is it because my queue is not being processed correctly?  For dequeuing the first queue input, I am using the following prescript:

```
            queue[0]<=queue[1];
            queue[1]<=queue[2]; 
             queue[2]<=queue[3];
             queue[3]<=queue[4];
             queue[4]<=queue[5];
             queue[5]<=queue[6];
             queue[6]<=queue[7];
             queue[7]<=queue[8];
             queue[8]<=queue[9];
             queue[9]<=queue[10];
             queue[10]<=queue[11];
             queue[11]<=queue[12];
             queue[12]<=queue[13];
             queue[13]<=queue[14];
             queue[14]<=queue[15];
             queue[15]<=queue[16];
             queue[16]<=queue[17];
             queue[17]<=queue[18];
             queue[18]<=queue[19];
```

I am also attaching the full Verilog code that I have written:

```verilog
   

module maze_lee(cost,clk,rst,error,temp,i);
input rst,clk;
output wire [4:0]cost;
wire grid[0:4][0:3];// 5x4 grid initialization
//Source and destination declaration
reg [2:0]source_c=3'b 001;
reg [2:0]source_r=3'b 001;
reg [2:0]dest_r= 3'b 100;
reg [2:0]dest_c= 3'b 011;
//declaration ended
reg [2:0]row;
reg [1:0]col;
reg [9:0]queue[0:19];
reg [4:0]costp;
output reg  [8:0]i;
assign grid[0][0]=1;
assign grid[0][1]=0;
assign grid[0][2]=1;
assign grid[0][3]=1;
assign grid[1][0]=0;
assign grid[1][1]=1;
assign grid[1][2]=1;
assign grid[1][3]=0;
assign grid[2][0]=1;
assign grid[2][1]=1;
assign grid[2][2]=0;
assign grid[2][3]=1;
assign grid[3][0]=0;
assign grid[3][1]=1;
assign grid[3][2]=1;
assign grid[3][3]=1;
assign grid[4][0]=1;
assign grid[4][1]=0;
assign grid[4][2]=1;
assign grid[4][3]=1;
//maze declaration ended
//Visited 2D array to check whether the respective grid has been visited or not
reg visited[4:0][3:0];
//direction array defined
wire signed [2:0]x[0:3];
wire signed [2:0]y[0:3];//signed type has to be used as the arrays values can be negative;
//Direction definer
assign x[0]=0;
assign x[1]=-1;
assign x[2]=1;
assign x[3]=0;
assign y[0]=-1;
assign y[1]=0;
assign y[2]=0;
assign y[3]=1;
//declaration of direction definer changed
output reg [9:0]temp;
reg [8:0]j;// index counter of the direction definer array.
output reg error;
reg temp11,temp21,temp31,temp41;
reg temp12,temp22,temp32,temp42;
reg [5:0]costf;

always@(posedge clk) begin
   if(rst)begin
     costp<=0;
     i<=0;
    queue[0]<={source_r,source_c,costp};
     queue[1]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[2]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[3]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[4]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[5]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[6]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[7]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[8]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[9]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[10]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[11]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[12]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[13]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[14]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[15]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[16]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[17]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[18]<=10'b 0000000000;
     queue[19]<=10'b 0000000000;
    visited[0][0]<=0;
     visited[0][1]<=0;
     visited[0][2]<=0;
     visited[0][3]<=0;
     visited[1][0]<=0;
     visited[1][1]<=0;
     visited[1][2]<=0;
     visited[1][3]<=0;
     visited[2][0]<=0;
     visited[2][1]<=0;
     visited[2][2]<=0;
     visited[2][3]<=0;
     visited[3][0]<=0;
     visited[3][1]<=0;
     visited[3][2]<=0;
     visited[3][3]<=0;
     visited[4][0]<=0;
     visited[4][1]<=0;
     visited[4][2]<=0;
     visited[4][3]<=0;       
     end
  else begin
    temp<=queue[0];
   if(temp!= 0)begin
        j<=0;
         row<=temp[9:7];
         col<=temp[6:5];
         costp<=temp[4:0];
         error<=0;
         if((row==dest_r)&&(col==dest_c))costf<=costp;
         else begin
            costf<=20;
            temp11<=grid[row+x[0]][col+y[0]];
             temp21<=grid[row+x[1]][col+y[1]];
             temp31<=grid[row+x[2]][col+y[2]];
             temp41<=grid[row+x[3]][col+y[3]];
            temp12<=visited[row+x[0]][col+y[0]];
             temp22<=visited[row+x[1]][col+y[1]];
             temp32<=visited[row+x[2]][col+y[2]];
             temp42<=visited[row+x[3]][col+y[3]];            
             if(((temp11==1)||(temp12==0))&&((row+x[0]>=0 && row+x[0]<=4)&&(col+y[0]>=0&&col+y[0]<=3)))begin // checks the validity of the left posistions
                 j<=j+1;
                  queue[i+j]<={(row+x[0]),(col+y[0]),costp+1};
                  visited[row+x[0]][col+y[0]]<=1;
                  end
             if(((temp21==1)||(temp22==0))&&((row+x[0]>=0 && row+x[0]<=4)&&(col+y[0]>=0&&col+y[0]<=3)))begin // checks the validity of the up posistions
                 j<=j+1;
                  queue[i+j]<={(row+x[1]),(col+y[1]),costp+1};
                  end
             if(((temp31==1)||(temp32==0))&&((row+x[0]>=0 && row+x[0]<=4)&&(col+y[0]>=0&&col+y[0]<=3)))begin // checks the validity of the right posistions
                 j<=j+1;
                  queue[i+j]<={(row+x[2]),(col+y[2]),costp+1};
                  end
             if(((temp41==1)||(temp42==0))&&((row+x[0]>=0 && row+x[0]<=4)&&(col+y[0]>=0&&col+y[0]<=3)))begin // checks the validity of the down posistions
                 j<=j+1;
                  queue[i+j]<={(row+x[3]),(col+y[3]),costp+1};
                  end
             i<=i+j;
            visited[row][col]<=1;
            // Time to dequeu the visited the grid.Confusion on whether to dequeue using Bruteforce method for now do it
            queue[0]<=queue[1];
            queue[1]<=queue[2]; 
             queue[2]<=queue[3];
             queue[3]<=queue[4];
             queue[4]<=queue[5];
             queue[5]<=queue[6];
             queue[6]<=queue[7];
             queue[7]<=queue[8];
             queue[8]<=queue[9];
             queue[9]<=queue[10];
             queue[10]<=queue[11];
             queue[11]<=queue[12];
             queue[12]<=queue[13];
             queue[13]<=queue[14];
             queue[14]<=queue[15];
             queue[15]<=queue[16];
             queue[16]<=queue[17];
             queue[17]<=queue[18];
             queue[18]<=queue[19];
             end
      end
      else begin
      temp<= 10'b 1110011001;
      error<=1;
      end
end
end
assign cost=costf;
endmodule
```

The main issues I am receiving is that the outputs are grounded completely.
That can be seen from the following screenshot.

[image: No output warnings]

I ran simulation on Altera's University Waveform program, and yes, the output was always at constant zero. I expect `cost` to change because inside the `if` statement that I have stated at the start of the body, there is `cost` increase whenever clock pulse covers one time period. But instead, it is constant. The main output is `cost` because it will determine the shortest path in the desired algorithm.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question has been significantly improved and all previously requested information has been added into the question. Therefore it has been reopened and the obsolete comments removed. Of the 3 original votes to close, 2 were for "needs details" (details have now been added) and 1 vote was invalid (voted to move it to Meta). If someone still wants to VTC, please also add a comment clearly stating why, so that specific point can be addressed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warnings show that `cost` is a constant.  This can be easily confirmed by running a Verilog simulation using a trivial testbench since you only have 2 inputs to your module:

```
module tb;
bit clk;
bit rst=1;

maze_lee dut (.clk(clk), .rst(rst));

always #5 clk++;

initial begin
    #33 rst=0;
    #500 $finish;
end
endmodule
```

The key is that you need to dump a waveform database that includes all signals inside your design module.  When you look at waveforms, you can see why `cost` is constant.

[image: waves]

`cost` is driven by `costf`, which is assigned the constant `20` (shown as hex `14` in waves).  `costf` never takes on another value because the following statement is never executed:

```
        if((row==dest_r)&&(col==dest_c))costf<=costp;
```

As you can see in waves, `row` does not equal `dest_r`.

---

If you find your code difficult to understand (as I do), there are some techniques you can use that may help.

There is a lot of code in one `always` block.  It may be easier to understand the code better if you split it up into several `always` blocks.  For example, you could move all assignments to `queue` into a separate `always` block.

When you see repeated code, like your assignments to `queue`, you could use a `for` loop.  This replaces 19 lines of code with 1 line:

```
           for (int ii=0; ii<19; ii++) queue[ii] <= queue[ii+1];
```

`for` loops are not just for testbench code; they are synthesizable.