# Error: Iteration limit reached within 195 ns

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, state-machines

This is an extension of the following post: [Queue values are not being accessed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/669397/333826)

As per the recommendation of the posts and using loops, I then tried to implement my problem using a Finite State Machine.  But, when I tried to simulate my program using University Program Waveform of Altera Quartus, the following error pops up in the simulation window even though the synthesis had no error.

> Error: Iteration limit reached within 195 ns

I am attaching the FSM part of the code:

```verilog
parameter IDLE=4'b 0000;
parameter ROW_COL_SELEC=4'b 0001;
parameter LEFT_CHECKER=4'b 0010;
parameter UP_CHECKER=4'b 0011;
parameter DOWN_CHECKER=4'b 0100;
parameter RIGHT_CHECKER=4'b 0101;
parameter ENQUEU_VALID=4'b 0110;
parameter DEQUEUE_FIRST=4'b 0111;
parameter FINAL_RESULT=4'b 1000;
//signal declaration for the queue element entry.
always @(posedge clk)begin
  if(rst)begin
      current_state<=IDLE;
       end
  else begin
      current_state<=next_state;
       end
       end
always @(*)begin
case(current_state)
IDLE:begin
   i<=0;
    costp<=0;
    j<=0;
    queue[0]<={source_r,source_c,costp};
    for(ii=1; ii<20; ii++)queue[ii]<=10'b 0000000000;
    for(ij=0;ij<5;ij++)begin
       for(ik=0; ik<4;ik++)begin
            visited[ij][ik]<=0;
             end
        end
    next_state<=ROW_COL_SELEC;
    end
ROW_COL_SELEC:begin
     temp<=queue[0];
       row<=queue[0][9:7];
       col<=queue[0][6:5];
       costp<=queue[0][4:0];
       if((row==dest_r) && col==dest_c)next_state<=FINAL_RESULT;
       else next_state<=LEFT_CHECKER;
       end
LEFT_CHECKER:begin
     if(((grid[row+x[0]][col+y[0]]==1)||(visited[row+x[0]][col+y[0]]==0))&&((row+x[0]>=0 && row+x[0]<=4)&&(col+y[0]>=0&&col+y[0]<=3)))begin // checks the validity of the left posistions
                         k<=1;           
                         end
       else k<=0;
       next_state<=UP_CHECKER;
       end
UP_CHECKER:begin
     if(((grid[row+x[1]][col+y[1]]==1)||(visited[row+x[1]][col+y[1]]==0))&&((row+x[1]>=0 && row+x[1]<=4)&&(col+y[1]>=0&&col+y[1]<=3)))begin // checks the validity of the up posistions
                     l<=1;
                     end
      else l<=0;
       next_state<=DOWN_CHECKER;
       end
DOWN_CHECKER:begin
     if(((grid[row+x[2]][col+y[2]]==1)||(visited[row+x[2]][col+y[2]]==0))&&((row+x[2]>=0 && row+x[2]<=4)&&(col+y[2]>=0&&col+y[2]<=3)))begin // checks the validity of the right posistions
                     m<=1;
                        end    
       else m<=0;
       next_state<=RIGHT_CHECKER;
       end
RIGHT_CHECKER:begin
     if(((grid[row+x[3]][col+y[3]]==1)||(visited[row+x[3]][col+y[3]]==0))&&((row+x[3]>=0 && row+x[3]<=4)&&(col+y[3]>=0&&col+y[3]<=3)))begin // checks the validity of the down posistions
                      n<=1;
                      end
       else n<=0;
       next_state<=ENQUEU_VALID;
       end 
ENQUEU_VALID:begin
                if((n==1) && (m==1) && (l==1) && (k==1))begin
                         queue[j+1]<={(row+x[0]),(col+y[0]),costp+1};
                         queue[j+2]<={(row+x[1]),(col+y[1]),costp+1};
                         queue[j+3]<={(row+x[2]),(col+y[2]),costp+1};
                         queue[j+4]<={(row+x[3]),(col+y[3]),costp+1};
                     j<=j+4;                 
                         end
                       else if((n==1) && (m==1) && (l==1)&&(k==0))begin
                         queue[j+1]<={(row+x[1]),(col+y[1]),costp+1};
                         queue[j+2]<={(row+x[2]),(col+y[2]),costp+1};
                         queue[j+3]<={(row+x[3]),(col+y[3]),costp+1};
                         j<=j+3;
                         end
                       else if((n==1) && (m==1) && (l==0)&&(k==1))begin
                         queue[j+1]<={(row+x[0]),(col+y[0]),costp+1};
                         queue[j+2]<={(row+x[2]),(col+y[2]),costp+1};
                         queue[j+3]<={(row+x[3]),(col+y[3]),costp+1};
                         j<=j+3;
                         end
                       else if((n==1) && (m==0) && (l==1)&&(k==1))begin
                         queue[j+1]<={(row+x[0]),(col+y[0]),costp+1};
                         queue[j+2]<={(row+x[1]),(col+y[1]),costp+1};
                         queue[j+3]<={(row+x[3]),(col+y[3]),costp+1};
                         j<=j+3;
                         end
                       else if((n==0) && (m==1) && (l==1)&&(k==1))begin
                           queue[j+1]<={(row+x[0]),(col+y[0]),costp+1};
                           queue[j+2]<={(row+x[1]),(col+y[1]),costp+1};
                           queue[j+3]<={(row+x[2]),(col+y[2]),costp+1};
                           j<=j+3;
                           end
                       else if((n==1) && (m==1) && (l==0)&&(k==0))begin
                           queue[j+1]<={(row+x[2]),(col+y[2]),costp+1};
                           queue[j+2]<={(row+x[3]),(col+y[3]),costp+1};
                           j<=j+2;
                           end
                       else if((n==1) && (m==0) && (l==1)&&(k==0))begin
                           queue[j+1]<={(row+x[1]),(col+y[1]),costp+1};
                           queue[j+2]<={(row+x[3]),(col+y[3]),costp+1};
                           j<=j+2;
                           end
                       else if((n==0) && (m==1) && (l==1)&&(k==0))begin
                           queue[j+1]<={(row+x[1]),(col+y[1]),costp+1};
                           queue[j+2]<={(row+x[2]),(col+y[2]),costp+1};
                           j<=j+2;
                           end
                       else if((n==0) && (m==1) && (l==0)&&(k==1))begin
                           queue[j+1]<={(row+x[0]),(col+y[0]),costp+1};
                           queue[j+2]<={(row+x[2]),(col+y[2]),costp+1};
                           j<=j+2;
                           end             
                       else if((n==0) && (m==0) && (l==1)&&(k==1))begin 
                           queue[j+1]<={(row+x[0]),(col+y[0]),costp+1};
                          queue[j+2]<={(row+x[1]),(col+y[1]),costp+1};
                           j<=j+2;
                           end 
                       else if((n==1) && (m==0) && (l==0)&&(k==1))begin 
                          queue[j+1]<={(row+x[0]),(col+y[0]),costp+1};
                           queue[j+2]<={(row+x[3]),(col+y[3]),costp+1};
                           j<=j+2;
                           end
                       else if((n==1) && (m==0) && (l==0)&&(k==0))begin 
                        queue[j+1]<={(row+x[3]),(col+y[3]),costp+1};
                           j<=j+1;
                           end
                      else if((n==0) && (m==1) && (l==0)&&(k==0))begin
                        queue[j+1]<={(row+x[2]),(col+y[2]),costp+1};
                           j<=j+1;
                           end
                      else if((n==0) && (m==0) && (l==1)&&(k==0))begin
                          queue[j+1]<={(row+x[1]),(col+y[1]),costp+1};
                           j<=j+1;
                           end
                       else if((n==0) && (m==0) && (l==0)&&(k==1))begin
                           queue[j+1]<={(row+x[0]),(col+y[0]),costp+1};
                            j<=j+1;
                            end
                       else  begin
                          queue[j]<=queue[j];
                           j<=j+0;
                           end
                      next_state<=DEQUEUE_FIRST;
                           end
DEQUEUE_FIRST:begin
                    visited[row][col]<=1;
                        for(int kk=0;kk<19;kk++)begin
                         queue[kk]<=queue[kk+1];
                          end
                           next_state<=ROW_COL_SELEC;
                           end
FINAL_RESULT:begin
                  costp<=costp;
                        if(rst)next_state<=IDLE;
                        else next_state<=FINAL_RESULT;
                        end
endcase
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error commonly occurs when you have a combinational loop in your code.  For example, look at the `costp` signal in this code:

```
always @(*)begin
case(current_state)
IDLE:begin
   i<=0;
    costp<=0;
    j<=0;
    queue[0]<={source_r,source_c,costp};
```

`always @*` is used to infer combinational logic.  You make an assignment to `costp` on the 5th line, then "read from" `costp` on the last line.  This can cause the simulator to trigger the  `always` block multiple times when `costp` changes.

You do the same thing with the `queue` signal.

You likely want to infer sequential logic for some of that, for example using:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
```

Again, your code might be simpler if you split up that big `always` block into more blocks.  For example, keep the logic that assigns to `next_state`, but consider making assignments to other signals in other blocks.

```
always @* begin
    case (current_state)
        IDLE            : next_state = ROW_COL_SELEC;
        ROW_COL_SELEC   : next_state = ((row==dest_r) && (col==dest_c)) ? FINAL_RESULT : LEFT_CHECKER;
        LEFT_CHECKER    : next_state = UP_CHECKER;
        UP_CHECKER      : next_state = DOWN_CHECKER;
        DOWN_CHECKER    : next_state = RIGHT_CHECKER;
        RIGHT_CHECKER   : next_state = ENQUEU_VALID;
        ENQUEU_VALID    : next_state = DEQUEUE_FIRST;
        DEQUEUE_FIRST   : next_state = ROW_COL_SELEC;
        FINAL_RESULT    : next_state = (rst) ? IDLE : FINAL_RESULT;
    endcase
end
```